# How to know which answer to accept when you don't know which one is the correct one

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

I have an old question ([Route to static file in Play! 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792875/route-to-static-file-in-play-2-0)) from Mar 20, 2012 which I still haven't accepted an answer for, and I have a few more with which I'm in the same position.

I would love to accept an answer, but I no longer work with the technology which I asked the question about and therefor no longer know which answer is correct.

What do you do in such a case?
You can go with the one which received the most up votes, but then again, maybe that one doesn't actually answers the question, but just helped more people (who were decent enough to up vote).
For example in the question I'm talking about, the one with the most up votes (15, and the one after it with 10) was posted when I was still using the technology and it did not answer my question (there's a comment there by me explaining how so).

I'd appreciate any idea of how to choose which answer to accept.
Also, I'm sorry if there's already a question about this case, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: In your situation I would just let things be, as I would only mark as accepted an answer that actually helped me.

Comment: Well, that's true, but what about the future viewers? It's usually helpful to be able to spot the correct answer without the need to browse through them all. And maybe one of those answers does in fact answer my original question perfectly, but I just don't know

Comment: Let the viewers figure it out. Of the acceptance check mark and the answer's upvote/downvote score, I find the score to be **much** more useful generally. OPs often accept answers that are suboptimal. Maybe the answer was posted quickly and helped the OP get out of a tight spot. Then the mark is fully warranted, but if I come around a year later, I don't want the suboptimal answer that got the OP out of a tight spot earlier. I want the best answer. Note that this means I use the scores as a very general guide, not that I'm going to blindly adopt the solution with the highest score.

Comment: If you don't know which answer is right, you don't accept any of them. It's that simple.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You accept an answer if an answer helped you. If no answer helped you, then don't accept an answer. Leave it to voters to provide feedback.

Comment: What if all helped you in their way?